# Known plaintext attack on ElGamal encryption

Tags: encryption, elgamal-encryption, known-plaintext-attack

Assume that Alice uses Bob’s ElGamal public key $(\alpha=2, \beta = 8, P= 11)$  to send two messages $M = 17$ and $M' = 37$ using the same random integer $k = 9$.  Eve intercepts the ciphertext and somehow she finds the value of $M = 17$.  Show how Eve can use a known-plaintext attack to find the value of $M’$.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  Sounds like an exercise.  We're not here to do your exercise for you; this is not a site where you can paste your exercise and we'll solve it for you.  Instead, we expect you to make a serious effort, to show us what you tried in the question, and to formulate a *specific* question about a *specific* aspect of the problem or your approach.

Answer (score 6):

Your parameters that you provide are incomplete (in what group are you working?).

Anyways, lets assume that you work in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, your have a generator $g$ and your public key is $y=g^x$.

Then, if two ciphertexts share the same randomness $k$, they will look like $(c_1,c_2)=(g^k,m\cdot y^k)$ and $(c_1',c_2')=(g^k,m'\cdot y^k)$ for your two messages $m$ and $m'$. So as you know that let say for the first ciphertext the message is $m$, then you can compute the inverse $m^{-1}$ of the message $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ and can find $y^k=c_2\cdot m^{-1}$. Now, as you have $y^k$ (which you can clearly also invert in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$) and both ciphertexts share the same randomness $k$, you can easily obtain $m'$ from $c_2'$.